# How do I cancel event bubbling in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-bubbling

I have a table cell (td) that triggers a script when clicked. I have a div within that table cell that triggers another div when clicked. I have successfully used the code below to cancel event bubbling (so the div event doesn't trigger the td event).

```
if (!e) var e = window.event;

e.cancelBubble = true;
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.returnValue = false;

if (e.stopPropagation)
{
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Everything works as it should in Chrome, Safari, and Opera. Why doesn't it prevent event bubbling in Firefox? Is there some kind of Firefox fix that I need to be aware of?

Comment: Can you link to a page showing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` stops other listeners from the same event to be called thus making `event.stopPropagation()` call after ineffective. Try using just `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this piece of code should be enough:

```
e = e || window.event;

if (e.stopPropagation) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}

// other piece of code here
```